# Git submodule update error

Tags: git

I'm starting to git right now, and running some tests to learn it better, but a got stucked on an error...

I've started a git repository of a framework I'm developing which is used on a lot projects I'm working on, to update these projects easily.

To test, I've started a new project and added the framework as a submodule. I've cloned the project on a new folder, executed the following commands `git submodule init; git submodule update` and the submodule was cloned into it's directory perfectly.

After that, I've made some modifications to the source accordingly to the project needs and committed the modifications made on the source and pushed to the server. Everything went fine.

On the another folder which I've cloned, I've pulled the modifications and everything seems to be ok.

```
DennyMac:app DennyLoko$ git commit -a -m "Teste"
[master 68fee42] Teste
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
DennyMac:app DennyLoko$ cd ..
DennyMac:vesti DennyLoko$ git add app
DennyMac:vesti DennyLoko$ git commit -m "Teste"
[master 3a2b13d] Teste
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
DennyMac:vesti DennyLoko$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 243 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@git.xxxxxxxxxx.com:vesti.git
   33fc470..3a2b13d  master -> master
```

But when I've checked the source of the modified file, nothing have changed. Running `git submodule update` it gives the following error:

```
DennyMac:testelol DennyLoko$ git submodule update
fatal: reference is not a tree: 68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6
Unable to checkout '68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6' in submodule path 'app'
```

What do I have to do to fix this? I'm doing the best thing using a submodule or exists a better approach to that?

Thank you guys!

EDIT::

Let's give more details...

I've created the framework project on Assembla and sent the initial structure by the following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "Estrutura inicial enviada"
git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:off.git
git push origin master
```

After that, I've created the directory for the new project:

```
mkdir vesti
cd vesti
mkdir documentacao
mkdir node_app
git init
git add .
git submodule init
git submodule add git@git.assembla.com:off.git app
git commit -a -m "Teste"
git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:vesti.git
git push origin master
```

After, I've created a new directory `mkdir testelol` and cloned `vesti` (`git clone git@git.assembla.com:vesti.git`) into this directory and executed the following commands:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Which run successful and automatically cloned the git@git.assembla.com:off.git inside the app directory. Backing to `vesti` dir (`cd ../vesti`), I've done the following:

- Edited a file inside the `app` submodule (`echo "teste" >> app/application/Main_Class.php`)
- Changed to `app` dir (`cd app`)
- Committed the modification (`git commit -a -m "Teste"` returned `[master 68fee42] Teste
  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)`)
- Backed to the root dir of the repo (`cd ..`)
- Added the `app` modifications (`git add app`)
- Committed (`git commit -m "Teste"` returned `[master 3a2b13d] Teste
  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)`)
- And pushed the modifications (`git push`)

.

```
DennyMac:vesti DennyLoko$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 243 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@git.assembla.com:vesti.git
   33fc470..3a2b13d  master -> master
```

After doing that all, I've backed to the `testelol` dir and executed the command `git pull` which returned the success message:

```
DennyMac:testelol DennyLoko$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From git@git.assembla.com:vesti.git
   33fc470..3a2b13d  master     -> origin/master
Fetching submodule app
Updating 33fc470..3a2b13d
Fast-forward
 app |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

After that I checked if the modification was made to the file `testelol/app/application/Main_Class.php` but wasn't been changed. To update I run the following commands:

```
DennyMac:testelol DennyLoko$ git submodule init
DennyMac:testelol DennyLoko$ git submodule update
fatal: reference is not a tree: 68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6
Unable to checkout '68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6' in submodule path 'app'
```

That's it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, your submodule is in 'app' and it was cloned explicitly, then added to the parent which already has the 'app' registered as a submodule.

If the parent repo already has had the submodule committed to it, then from that projects working tree rootdir, enter `git submodule update --init --recursive` (the --recursive is only needed if your submodules have submodles)

You can look at the contents of .gitmodules to see what's registered (and remember to commit the .gitmodules file whenever it changes). Also you have to manually remove lines from .gitmodules and commit it when removing submodules.

Comment: No. To add the submodule I've used `git submodule add remote_path local_dir`. Now I've excluded the second directory, created a new dir, cloned the repo again and when I execute `git submodule update` returns the error `fatal: reference is not a tree: 68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6
Unable to checkout '68fee423f5dba537956fec51dcab0901856ad4e6' in submodule path 'app'`.

Comment: Please use actual directory names (or consistent aliases) to be clearer. So all this is on one machine. The first time submodule was added using `git submodule add remote_path local_dir` then excluded (with .gitignore?) and then a different directory was created (with mkdir app ?) and a remote repo cloned into it?

If you can post the contents of .gitmodules in the parent working directory. It should only list the submodules you want in the directories you want them. If there's extra, remove the [submodule path] block and the following 'path' and 'url' lines.